# Get current order ID magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, session

I know how to retrieve last order id by this code,

```
$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getReservedOrderId();
```

Where _checkoutSession is obtained with the injection,

```
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
```

I want to know how to get the current order ID in magento 2.

Comment: At which place you want current order id?

Comment: After the order is placed @Nalin. I am observing order placed after event.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

below code will give you last order id

```
protected $_checkoutSession;


public function __construct(
 .....
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,

.....
) {

        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;


    }

 $order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
 $orderId=$order->getEntityId();
 $order->getIncrementId();
```

[Reference](https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Magento-2-15-Get-order-ID-in-a-custom-controller-in-custom/m-p/64036#M1937)

Comment: ++1 from me, and how to get the increment id, insted of entity id ?

Comment: ummm.. ! i guess $order->getIncrementId() should work

Comment: Okay saif I will check..

Comment: @DishaSingh i updated the code..